# How to get onclick working with form submit button?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have

```
<%= form_for(@lesson_feedback, remote: true) do |f| %>

<%= f.select :feedback, options_for_select([["Great and helpful", "Great and helpful"], ["Clear and interesting but not what I'm looking for", "Clear and interesting but not what I'm looking for"], ["Okay but not interesting","Okay but not interesting"], ["Unclear or confusing", "Unclear or confusing"] ]) %>

<!-- Lesson ID -->
<%= f.hidden_field :lesson_id, :value => @lesson.id %>

<%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-success" , :value => "Send feedback" %>

<!-- :confirm => 'Your confirm message' -->
<!-- :onclick => "clearContents();" -->

<% end %>
```

Specifically for the below line...

```
<%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-success" , :value => "Send feedback" %>
```

The above works fine. However, when I add

```
<%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-success" , :onclick => "clearContents();", :value => "Send feedback" %>
```

the clearContents JS executes but the data doesn't get set anymore. The JS is:

```
<script>
function clearContents() {
    document.getElementById("feedback_module").innerHTML = "Thanks for your feedback! We appreciate you taking the time to leave us feedback, and we're doing our best to improve our content.";
}

</script>
```

Comment: Which of those have the `id` `feedback_module`?

Comment: Can we use JQuery or just JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an absence of answers, here's my take on it for you:

--

**Ajax**

Because you're using the [Rails UJS Ajax driver](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax), you'll want to capture the response from the remote server, allowing you to populate the feedback element on your form accordingly:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:success", "#your_form", function() {
   $("#feedback_module").html("Thanks for your feedback");
});
```

--

[**Unobtrusive**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

The main point I'd wish to make is that you want to make sure you keep your javascript as unobtrusive as possible. What is this? It's basically where you keep your javascript bindings & calls *outside* of your views

There are several reasons why this is preferred, nay, recommended - most notably because you will end up with a much more [modular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) application. This gives you the flexibility to create & use all the functionality you want throughout your application, without keeping it constricted to a single element / piece of functionality

So bottom line is that you need to reconsider your code to actually work outside the scope of your view. If you do that, then you'll be able to unobtrusively bind the call, like as above, to make it a much more efficient system